# How do I click_link with Capybara that has a method: :post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

In my application, I have this link:

```
link_to 'Start', some_path, method: :post
```

and, in a feature test, I need to click this link and then assert that the page does not contain this link (instead, it should contain a 'Stop' link)

I tried to:

```
click_link 'Start'
```

but it does not work - either the link Start is still on the page or I am getting a page with a 'getting redirected' text (I use save_and_open_page)

How do I solve this issue?

EDIT: I am using the poltergeist driver.

Comment: Are you using selenium driver?

Comment: @IgorPantović I am using the poltergeist driver.

Comment: It would be wise if you switch to selenium driver first to see what is happening. This should help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

To avoid js/browser overhead you can also do a fake click with pure ruby.
For example `click_ujs_link "Send"` with this code.

```
def click_ujs_link(name)
  link = find(:link, name, {})
  visit_with_method link['data-method'], link['href']
end

def visit_with_method(method, url)
  page.driver.send method, url
  visit page.driver.response.location
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the solution is trivial: just set js: true on the scenarios that contain the link, like for example this:

```
scenario 'some description', js: true do
```

The explanation: for links with methods other than GET, Rails.js dynamically generates a form, something like this

```
<a href="url" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">...</a>
```

so you need to tell Capybara that it should run the scenario using a javascript engine (poltergeist, in our case), and you do so via the js: true option.